# Wordpress Editor link is missing, after adding multisite network

Tags: wordpress, editor, multisite

After adding multisite network, for my domain and subdomain the "editor" link in "Appearance" and "Plugin" is missing in Wordpress.

Can someone say why ?

I do not have this in wp_config.php

```html
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the admin dashboard of the main site. This is normal. Now that you have a network, the editor is only visible in the [network admin dashboard](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin).

Comment: Yes can see that, but there is ONE theme, so if I changes something in the header file it's for both sites/domains...
Is that bc. I have installed both sites in public_html ? and I needed to use an subfolder for the subdomain ?

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen This is the whole point of multisite, to not have separate WordPress installations, and just have the plugins and themes and core files only on one place and use them for all sites. You can make a child theme though (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) that is changed and use it on one of the sites, and use the original on the other site.